# PowerShell Script Returning Unexpected Output (random numbers)

Tags: powershell, file-upload, httpserver

**Problem**
I am writing a script in PowerShell that uploads a file to an http server. The upload completes successfully, but its returning a bunch of numbers in the console upon execution (far more than what is displayed below).

Output:
[image]

Here's the script I'm running:

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
       [string]$user,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
       [string]$pass,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
       [string]$dir,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
       [string]$fileName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=5)]
       [string]$url 
 )

$filePath = ("$dir" + "$fileName")

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
    $webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$user", "$pass");
    ("*** Uploading {0} file to {1} ***" -f ($filePath, $url) ) | write-host -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor White
    $webClient.UploadFile($url, "PUT", $filePath);
```

**Question**
Where are these numbers coming from, and how do I suppress them?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell version 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the numbers are the output coming from `$webClient.UploadFile`. Try adding `> $null` after it, like this:

```
$webClient.UploadFile($url, "PUT", $filePath) > $null;
```

This should send the output to null, making those numbers not display. Unfortunately I am unable to test this particular situation myself.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly and does not suppress the message I wanted it to display (***Uploading...***).

Comment: I had the exact same problem.  UploadFile is a method on the webclient so I don't understand where these numbes are coming from.