# WebClient HTTP upload - "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Tags: powershell, upload

Hoping someone can offer some advice with this - it may be that I've been staring at my screen too long so apologies if I'm missing the obvious!

Within a script I'm trying to add an upload/download speedtest to my webserver, but I'm having an issue trying to upload a file to my webserver via HTTP(s) in Powershell. I can get download working no problem.

The upload snippet of my script is as follows:

```
$uploadPath = "https://www.domain.co.uk/speedtest/up/"
$localfile = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\100MB.bin"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UploadFile($localfile, $uploadPath)
```

I've tried over HTTP & HTTPS, file permissions are currently 777 on the "up" folder on the server (just as a test) and I've also tried $uploadPath as:
`"https://www.domain.co.uk/speedtest/up/100MB.bin"`.

The following is the error received when running the upload section of the script:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At C:\Users\User\desktop\uploadtest.ps1:4 char:1
+ $wc.UploadFile($localfile, $uploadPath)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

(file paths etc are just temporary for this test too)

Any suggestions you can make would be appreciated! I'd ideally like to use the webclient method (if possible) as the download uses the same method.

Comment: I think `$wc.UploadFile($localfile, $uploadPath)` should be `$wc.UploadFile($uploadPath, $localfile)` See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I'm getting the same results as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419198/powershell-script-returning-unexpected-output-random-numbers). Adding null stops the output but the file still doesn't upload.

Comment: You could try `$null = $wc.UploadFile($uploadPath, "PUT",  $localfile)`

Comment: In my experience this is something to do with the file. Are you sure it is not open in another process? Are you sure the file is not still open in whatever program that downloaded it?

Comment: Also, are you trying to run the PS script manually or as a scheduled task?

Comment: Also, your webclient object does not have authentication information (username, password)

Comment: @AleX_ - the file is not open, as I have tried this section of the script on a new file and had the same result. I'm running the script manually, and also running it without authentication information as the folder has 777 permissions (allow public users to write - this is just temporary while testing the script)

Comment: Oddly, the upload seems to run, I get the output as per my above link, but the file never appears on the web server. The speed result seems to be accurate too, so maybe not a major issue in my case.

Comment: @Theo - sorry I missed your last comment. I will try this once I'm back at my PC too - thanks!